# Inherit execution of static initializer blocks in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, static-initializer, es2022

I have code like:

```js
class A {
    static {
        console.log("A");
    }
}
class B extends A {
    static {
        console.log("B");
    }
}
```

Why doesn't it print `A` twice? I would like a way in JavaScript to execute code of a class whenever it is extended. Is there any way to achieve this?

Of course I could just add a static method in `A` myself and call it after declaring `B`, but I wonder if this is already possible via ES2022.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is designed like that. The static initializer is only called once for the class that is initialized. It's a big shame though. It would have enabled a subclassing hook in Javascript which is absolutely missing if you want to avoid the use of factory methods.

Comment: I'm sure there are valid reasons for it to be designed that way. But that's super unhelpful because I don't want to have to copy that logic into ~30 (and growing) subclasses. Isn't that what base classes are for?